# To reach xslt variable from different xsl file?

Tags: html, css, xslt, web

I define xslt variable and try to reach its value from diferent xsl file.

```
<xsl:variable name="ServiceError" select="'error'"> </xsl:variable>
and try to reach ServiceErrorCheck = "<xsl:value-of select='$ServiceError'/>";
```

from different xsl file
and I get error message "Could not find variable with the name of ServiceError"

Answer (score 0):

You should include the other xslt file

Please check this http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_include.asp and this 
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_import.asp